# Show user specific data from database based on LoginID username

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, login-control

I am attempting to convert an online game i have written in ASP into ASP.NET,, but I am failing at a very early and probably a very amateurish stage.

I am using a Sample ASPX project.
There is an ASPNETDB database included, when i register my username is added to the DB along with a userID and various other fields.   This is stored in a table called aspnet_Users.

The Login Control is stored in a Site.Master file

```
<div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" 
                onviewchanged="HeadLoginView_ViewChanged">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
```

I have created a new table called tblClubs, which stores information such as ClubName, StadiumCapacity etc
I added a field called 'Owner' and this is directly related to the UserName field in the aspnet_Users table

What I am trying to solve is to show user specific information from the database, based on their LoginID.

i.e

My username is Laclerque and my club is called Racing Mongoose, the stadium capacity is 9500..  the information for each User needs to be different and just show the information that is relevant to them.

obviously in the longer term, there is going to be 100's of these associations required for the full game, but not until i can get my head around the basics of how to set this information.  I tend to work better when i can see a working sample, and then adapt things to suit my needs.

Hope this is enough information, and thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at asp.net's online example: [Here](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/login/loginstatus.aspx)

Hope that helps!